# how to resolve "return" statement problem in a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, return

I have few lines of code like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_segments(path):

    """
    Read the segment input file.

    Args:
    path (str): path to input segment csv file.

    Returns:
    (pandas Dataframe) segments as pandas DataFrame
    """

    return pd.read_csv("C:/Users/bobo/OneDrive/Documents/workspace/data/1868/segment_1868.csv", sep=";").drop(columns=["segment_name"])

def read_data(datafile):
    data = []
    with open(datafile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line != '':
                d = [float(i) for i in line.split()]
                data.append(d)
    return data

def read_weights(weightfile):
    weights = []
    with open(weightfile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            weights += [float(i) for i in line.strip().split()]
    return weights
```

After running the code, i got this error : `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` at line `return pd.read_csv`  i.e, the code execution stops at this line

am a little bit wondering because the `return` statement is not outside the function

what could be the reason and how do i resolve this?

Comment: Did you get that error pasting your code into a repl, instead of running it from a file? Behavior is not quite the same, _especially_ when your code has blank lines in it.

Comment: See also https://ideone.com/FmTU7z, code copied-and-pasted from the question, stated problem not reproduced.

Comment: what does ```repl``` stands for? I typed the code. it wasnt copied and paste

Comment: @kukulu Read-Eval-Print-Loop -- the interactive Python interpreter.

Comment: REPL == read/eval/print loop; the thing that Python starts when you just type `python` at the command line.

Comment: In the REPL, typing a blank line ends the current block statement, so the blank line after the documentaiton comment ends the function.

Comment: @ charles, your link was helpful